# How to use env from reusable workflow in main pipeline?

Tags: github-actions

I have a reusable workflow where I have sent one value via `env` like below:

```yaml
- name: 'reusable_workflow'
  run : |
    echo "value=$variable_name" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Now, I need to use the same value in my main pipeline. How can I achieve this?

Below is the main pipeline where I need to use `value`:

```yaml
- name: 'main_pipeline'
  run: |
    echo "${{ env.value }}"
```

**Both are the separate workflows and repos are different.**

Comment: See [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).

Comment: It can be used within the same workflow file. I am looking to call it to the another workflow

Comment: Please add the rest of your workflow where you're using it. What's the error that you're facing? Using an env var should be the same i.e. via `env` context or under `run` with the respective shell-specific syntax.

Comment: I am not getting any error but when i am calling the github env in main pipeline from the reusable workflow, i am getting only blank, No result. Both are the separate workflow and separate repo in same organization. I am able to get the env result in same workflow but not in the separate workflow.

Comment: See [Using outputs from a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-outputs-from-a-reusable-workflow).

Comment: According to the [Limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations) of reusable workflows, "**Any environment variables set in an env context defined at the workflow level in the caller workflow are not propagated to the called workflow.**". From your use case, seems like that the opposite is also not supported but it's not listed under limitations. Maybe, that's why there's this dedicated section on [using outputs from a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-outputs-from-a-reusable-workflow).

Comment: Relevant issue created: https://github.com/github/docs/issues/25620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations) of [Reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows):

> Any environment variables set in an `env` context defined at the workflow level in the caller workflow are not propagated to the called workflow.

and,

> Similarly, environment variables set in the `env` context, defined in the called workflow, are not accessible in the `env` context of the caller workflow. Instead, **you must use outputs of the reusable workflow**.

also,

> Reusable workflows are called directly within a job, and not from within a job step. You cannot, therefore, use `GITHUB_ENV` to pass values to job steps in the caller workflow.

See [Using outputs from a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-outputs-from-a-reusable-workflow) to share values from the reusable workflow.